# Animation gets broken into separate action for each bone on FBX import

Tags: animation, bones, import, .fbx, actions

This is what happened when I imported an FBX with animations from Akeytsu with the "Fully Baked" option:

[image: Several Actions, one for each animation, fully baked frames]

Each animation became an action and all is well!

But when I try to import an FBX without a "fully baked" animation, this happens:
[image: Several Actions, one for each bone because Blender is the devil]

The animation has been split into an animation for each and every bone for some god forsaken reason.

Unfortunately for me, all of my newer animations are using UMotion in Unity, which does not have a bake option on export. Is there some special way to import animations that fixes this problem? Also I'd love to know why it's doing this to begin with!

Thanks in advance!

Edit:
My back and forth with the UMotion creator seems to debunk the theory that the animation needs to be baked.
https://support.soxware.com/en/communities/1/topics/823-is-it-possible-to-bake-animations-on-export#

Comment: Also having this problem.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I know I used to be able to import animations just fine, but something happened... maybe I changed a setting or something... and now I get one animation per bone. I've tried it with several models that I know used to import just fine. What the heck is going on?! 